# How can I ORDER BY a column that isn't in the SELECT list when I use GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql

I wrote this line in mysql and it works

```sql
SELECT
    IDKartoch,
    SUM(SummOpl) AS Total
FROM
    Oplata
GROUP BY 
    IDKartoch
HAVING
    SUM( Oplata.SummOpl ) >= 0
ORDER BY
    IDKartoch;
```

And I get this result:

[image]

But after I remove the `IDKartoch` column from the `SELECT`...

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(SummOpl) AS Total
FROM
    Oplata
GROUP BY
    Oplata.IDKartoch 
HAVING
    SUM( Oplata.SummOpl ) >= 0
ORDER BY
    Oplata.IDKartoch;
```

I get this error

> Function or column reference to '`IDKartoch`' in the `ORDER BY` clause its
> invalid SQLCODE=-854

Comment: You just *removed* the column that you wanted to ORDER BY.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `SELECT DISTINCT`? Using `SELECT DISTINCT` when you're also already using `GROUP BY` is a bad code-smell which might be hiding important data and is a common cause of duplicate row values which are meant to be unique.

Comment: Just checked. DISTINCT doesnt change the output

Comment: Good, you should remove the `DISTINCT` keyword then.

Comment: Edited the question, Thanks. But ORDER BY still doesnt work

Comment: `ORDER BY` gets ran after the data is retrieved, so there is no way to sort by a column that you didn't retrieve. Read up on the order of execution [here](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution).

Comment: @Jesse The trick is to use an inner derived-table - see my answer.

Comment: Your error message is a sybase error message, not mysql. You can order by the column, even if it is not in the select list, as long as it *could* be there (e.g. is functional dependent on the group by). Your query should work in mysql and most (if not all) other databases, see e.g. [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff5333/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The syntax `ORDER BY Oplata.IDKartoch` has a *fully qualified* reference to the `Oplata` "`BASE TABLE`" (as opposed to a `VIEW` or derived-table).
- However, when you use `GROUP BY` in a query your query now represents an anonymous *derived-table*, which is what `ORDER BY` sees, and this derived-table is *not* the same object as `Oplata`.

  - That's why it complains about the missing column: the column simply doesn't exist anymore.
- Anyway, you **can** order rows by a column that isn't in the `SELECT` clause, but it's  a bit gnarly....

  - Also, note that (in ISO SQL, I don't know about MySQL), the `ORDER BY` clause can only be used in the outermost (non-CTE) `SELECT` query step of a nontrivial query (because [relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) are sets, which are unordered).

The trick is to take the existing `( IDKartoch, Total )` query-result (actually "derived table") from your current query, and wrap it in an outer-query which aliases the derived-table (allowing `ORDER BY IDKartoch` while *only* having `Total` in the outermost `SELECT` clause.

Like so (tested in MySQL 5.6):

```sql
SELECT
    q.Total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            IDKartoch 
            SUM(SummOpl) AS Total
        FROM
            Oplata
        GROUP BY
            IDKartoch 
        HAVING
            SUM( Oplata.SummOpl ) >= 0
    ) AS q
ORDER BY
    q.IDKartoch;
```

[Here's a SQLFiddle demonstrating a similar `SELECT` query that is able to sort the rows by a "hidden" column `hiddenSortColumn`.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97f60bb/4/0)

Comment: Yes, the columns of the original table and the aggregated one live in different scopes.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this is not necessary for sql in general or mysql in particular. You *can* order by a column that is not in the select list, as long as it would be valid in the select list (e.g. is functional dependent on the group). See e.g. [your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff5333/2). The error message the op has is a sybase error. I don't know sybase, but the problem may be specific to sybase (and your solution might be needed there). All (or most) other databases should not have a problem with that query.